# Understanding 'onLoginFinished' function on 'LoginButton' component of react native fbsdk

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Hi I'm trying to test react native facebook sdk for facebook login. Using below code I'm able to successfully give in my credentials and log in to app. My question is i'm not getting the alert message or console.log output. Even the debugger statement seems not working. Can someone help me to figure out how to correctly handle onLoginFinished event.

```js
                          <View>
                       <LoginButton
                        //  publishPermissions={["none"]}
                          readPermissions = {["public_profile"]}
                           onLoginFinished={
                             (error, result) => {
                               debugger;
                               if (error) {
                                 alert("login has error: " + result.error);
                                 console.log("Error occured");
                               } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                 alert("login is cancelled.");
                                 console.log("Login canceled");
                               } else {
                                 // I don't see this alert or console.log anywhere     
                                 alert("Login success");
                                 console.log("Login Success");
                               } // end else
                             }
                        }

                         onLogoutFinished={() => { alert("User logged out");}}

                         />
                       </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

What I found is that You need to always build your app again with the command `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` for the changes to actually take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem after going through this.[https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk](http://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) In my MainActivity class I was using CallbackManager instance locally initiated. After referring to CallbackManager instance of MainApplication class, onLoginFinished functioned triggered!! :)

please refer : https://reactnativecode.com/facebook-login-integration/

Answer (score 1):

i think you debugger have issue but i am using this code thats working fine. can you check onLoginFinished method is called or not .

```
<LoginButton 
     publishPermissions={[“publish_actions”]}
     onLoginFinished={
       (error, result) => {
         (error) {
             alert(“Login failed with error: “ + result.error);
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             alert(“Login was cancelled”);
         } else {
             alert(“Login was successful with permissions: “ 
                 + result.grantedPermissions)
         }
      }
    }
    onLogoutFinished={() => alert(“User logged out”)}
/>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I've tried putting console.log in very first line of the function as follows, but i don't get the output in console.    onLoginFinished={
                                 (error, result) => {
                                   console.log("Inside onLoginFinished method");  How ever i do get the console.log output from very first line inside render() method